# Как при запуске java программы передать аргуметы через переменные окружения

Tags: java, windows, передача-данных

Стоит задача передать переменные среды при запуске java программы (maven проект)
Правильно ли я понимаю, что сначала нужно создать 2 переменные(к примеру) со значениями в переменных средах windows, и потом каким-то образом передать из в мою программу (например в метод sum()). Я должен как-то поместить их в String[] args?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переменную окружения можно просто получить при помощи специально заготовленного на этот случай метода:

```
  String value = System.getenv(String name);
```

При этом если вызвать одноименный метод без агрументов, можно получить их сразу все:

```
 Map<String,String> vars = System.getenv();
```

PS: Это мало относится напрямую к вопросу, однако так же есть отдельная возможность получить аргументы запуска jvm:

```
 String value = System.getProperty(key);
```

Comment: Я создал переменную среды numb1 и указал значение 10.
Потом в классе main выполнил String value = System.getenv(String name);
System.out.println(value); и получил в консоль null. Почему не 10?

Comment: @Artem вы как запускаете полграмму?

Comment: @Artem эв windows это может быть иза того что консоль или ide были запущены до установки переменной

Comment: Вообще должен быть jar файл, но сейчас у меня с ним проблемы (Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile), поэтому я пока запустил через Idea --> Run

Comment: @Artem перезапустите ide после создания новой переменной окружения, а если она зарущена из консоли то её

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: еще вопрос, можно ли каким-то образом из Java класса изменить значение переменной среды?

Comment: @Artem боюсь что нет